# Vuetify v-card component overflow-x is not working

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

My latest project, I used Nuxt.js (v2.15.3) and Vuetify.js(v2.4.9) as UI framework.

I tried to use overflow-x in v-card component but it wasn't work.
My simple test code is below.

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <v-sheet>
      <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="4">
          <v-card height="200px" width="200px" class="scroll">
            <v-card-text>
              <v-treeview
                :items="items"
                item-key="id"
                item-name="name"
                item-children="child"
                open-all
              >
              </v-treeview>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="8"></v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-sheet>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue {
  items: any = [
    {
      id: 'test',
      name: '1stTree',
      child: [
        { id: 'Test#2', name: '2ndTree' },
        {
          id: 'test#2',
          name: '2ndTree',
          child: [
            { id: 'Test#2#3', name: '3rdTree' },
            {
              id: 'test#2#3',
              name: '3rdTree',
              child: [{ id: 'Test#2#3#4', name: '4thTreeTestTestTestTest' }],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.scroll {
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
</style>
```

And I want to add the scroll bar in bottom of the v-card component,
but x axis scroll bar isn't see only can see bar like below my sample photo.

[image]

Thanks for the comments, I understood why only show scroll bar in x axis.
"overflow-x:scroll" was force the scroll bar to always appear.
I thought content exceed the container's size, but it wasn't.
If I see the inner scroll bar, how should I do?
And is it possible to use "overflow:auto"?
I don't want to use "overflow-x:scroll" to force show scroll if possible.
Does anyone advise me, please?

Comment: What problem do you have? The `overflow-x: hidden` inside `Inherited from html` isn't applied to your v-card. The style from `.scroll[data-v-0129536c]` is, so your scroll bars should appear when they are needed like you wanted.

Comment: I want to apply the style from .scroll[data-v-0129536c] is ,especially "overflow-x" part. So I want to know how to reject "overflow-x:hidden"  from "Inherited from html".  Is it possible?

Comment: It is being applied. That's why the `overflow-x: hidden` is opaque. It means it's not being applied. Switch to your `computed` tab instead of the `style` tab in your chrome browser, and type in `overflow` to to see what is actually being applied to your v-card.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I confirmed the "computed" tab in my chrome browser, it was applied to my v-card you said. but I want to display scrollbar in bottom of v-card. why it is not displayed even if being applied to v-card?

Comment: Because you set it to `auto` which means "when the content exceeds the size of the container, then show the scroll bar." You need to set it to `overflow: scroll;` or `overflow-x: scroll;` to force the scroll bar to always appear. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_force_scrollbars.asp

Comment: FYI `overflow-x: scroll;` will force the scroll bar to always appear, but if the content doesn't exceed the container's size then you won't see the inner scroll bar because all of the content is currently being displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I really understand why scroll bar wasn't showed. I thought content exceed the container's size cuz overflow "..." showd. but it was not recognized to exceed in broswer.

Comment: If I show the scroll bar, what should I do for my code?

Comment: You will need probably have set a fixed width on your `v-card-text` that is greater than the width of your `v-card`. Or you can try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to your `v-card-text` so that the text in your `v-card-text` components stays on one line. Here are some examples.  https://jsbin.com/pomowikevi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I think what you want to do is just leave the `overflow-x:scroll` and then add more trees in your `items` object to make sure it will show the scroll bar if the trees go off of the screen. Try adding like tree 4 and tree 5.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! I will try again!!